# What is a foldable column?

Tags: apache-spark

One of the variants of [schema_of_json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#schema_of_json(json:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) accepts a column containing a JSON String. The documentation of the parameter says that the column must be

> a foldable string column containing a JSON string.

[image: scaladoc]

What is the exact meaning of *foldable column* in this context?

Comment: So if I understand the answer correctly, the `schema_of_json` is only allowed on a literal string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on document [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/7d496fb361cfa885515a91d90669af2b9cc3a45e/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/Expression.scala#L99):

> Returns true when an expression is a candidate for static evaluation before the query is executed.
> The following conditions are used to determine suitability for constant folding:
>
> - A Coalesce is foldable if all of its children are foldable
> - A BinaryExpression is foldable if its both left and right child are foldable
> - A Not, IsNull, or IsNotNull is foldable if its child is foldable
> - A Literal is foldable
> - A Cast or UnaryMinus is foldable if its child is foldable